# constrained optimization with decreasing constraint thresholds -Literature tips

Tags: optimization, constraint, lagrange-multipliers

consider a constrained optimization problem (typically c=0), with f highly nonlinear:
\begin{equation}
\text{minimize}_x f(x) \\\\ s.t \ \ \ \ g(x) \leq c
\end{equation}

I experimented a bit and found empirically that (at least for my problem) constraint optimization methods lead to an much better (constrained satisfying) optimimum, when the constraint threshold c is not directly set to zero, but chosen higher in the beginning and then lowered gradually to approach zero. The higher threshold probably allows to explore more freely and then when a good region is found, one can lower the threshold.

Are there any constrained optimization methods (I am f.ex thinking of exterior penalty methods), that use a decreasing constraint threshold? Or penalty methods with an increasing penalty term (which should behave similarly). If yes, are there some good papers on theoretic guarantees of these methods or papers that compare them to traditional methods?

Comment: This is called a homotopy (path following) method. First solve an easy problem. Use the solution as starting point for a new problem which is closerr to the problem you want to solve. Eventually solve the problem you want to solve. How the "easy" problem differs from the problem you want to solve can depend on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a starting point what to look into.

Comment: It kind of reminds me of funnel methods where the test to accept a new point is made more and more strict with respect to constraint violation.

Comment: This is related to predictor-corrector methods used in various contexts (solving differential equations, LP interior point methods, ...).